# hadoop,hdfs,source code reading,what Class.method() tell where to write?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

FSDataOutputStream.java is the Class that is used to write things.

so which datanode to write ? which Class is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a clients wants to write to a DataNode it contact the NameNode. NameNode in turn, with the help of block location map generated based on the block reports sent by the DataNodes, tells the client which particular DataNode has free blocks where data can be written. Then the client starts writing to that node directly without having to interact with the NameNode. So this is random based on the availability of space. It can be any one node among the n nodes in cluster.

As a particular DataNode accumulates some considerable amount of data it starts pushing the data to other nodes to create replicas(based on your replication factor). So a DataNode might be both reading and writing at the same time.

The class `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.BlocksMap` maintains the map from a block to its metadata.

HTH